# Haskell concat Int

Tags: haskell, int, concatenation

I am having trouble with the following exercise:

I must make a function named addDigit, which takes two Int's, the second one being between 0 and 9, and return an Int that is the first Int followed by the second one.

Example:

input: `addDigit (-123) 4`

output: `-1234`

what I have tried is the following :

```
addDigit :: Int -> Int -> Int
addDigit x y = x ++ y
```

I get it doesn't work because the ++ keyword only works with strings, chars and lists (i think), and this is supposed to be solved in a simple way without changing the Int's to Strings or any sort of other variables, but i have no clue at all on how to do it.

Comment: Look at what happens when you multiply a number by 10...

Comment: Just to clarify about the (++) function: it only works with lists. Strings are lists of chars, which is why it works with strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to solve the problem graphically (thinking of the integers as strings), you want to treat it as a numerical problem. For positive values, appending a digit is accomplished by the following function.

```
addDigitPositive a b = 10 * a + b
```

This will unfortunately *not* work if `a < 0`. Under those circumstances we would have to *subtract* `b`. We can incorporate this functionality easily with function guards.

```
addDigit a b | a < 0     = a * 10 - b
             | otherwise = a * 10 + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could solve it graphically, by converting the numbers to strings using `show` and then concatenating them with `(++)`:

```
addDigit :: Int -> Int -> String
addDigit x y = (show x) ++ (show y)
```

Now, if you still want an Int as the output, you can convert the string to an Int using `read`:

```
addDigit :: Int -> Int -> Int
addDigit x y = read ((show x) ++ (show y))
```

As you can see, there is more than one way to skin a cat.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The asker specifically said that he did _not_ want a solution that involved "changing the Ints to Strings".